# How do I say "share with me" in Chinese?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, syntax

I'd like to know how to form a sentence such as, "He shared this information with me," "She shared her recommendations with me." I believe the "with" here is not 跟，和 or 与, since the "sharing" action is not joint or communal. Instead, it's what one person "gives," in a sense, to another. Would 分享 ever apply to this type of "share," or is it 送, or is it something like "他给我分享。。。"? What would I say in the case of, "He shared this song with me?"

Any help clarifying this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: see jukuu, e.g., share information:共享信息，沟通信息，分享信息，

Answer (score 1):

**He shared this song with me**

All the following translations are correct and common, you can use them interchangeably in a loose environment, say daily conversation, normal text.

**Suggest sharing**

他跟我分享了这首歌. 
他和我分享了这首歌.
他与我分享了这首歌.
他同我分享了这首歌.

**Suggest owner**

他给我分享了这首歌.

Answer (score 1):

With context, X 跟/和/与 Y分享了... can mean the same thing that X initiated the sharing.

Without context, X 和/与 Y 分享了... can mean either way, although it is more likely to be understood as X initiated the sharing to Y, so you might need to add clarification if it's the other way. 跟 will always mean X initiated.

If you does not want to indicate who initiated the sharing, you can use 我们分享了... as in English "we shared..."

Answer (score 0):

Format: A share something with B.

In this format: 
"A" and "B" can be he, she, we and so on. 
"share" can be other tense like shared, shares and so on
"something" can be happiness, info, book and so on.

Translation: A 与/同/和/跟 B 一起分享了something.

"Share" should be used at least between two people. No matter in Chinese or in English, the sentence "I share a book with me" does not make sense. You can understand in this way, A share something with B = A share something with B (together).